# Translate SQL to lambda LINQ with GroupBy and Average

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, average

I spend a few hours trying to translate simple SQL to lambda LINQ

```
SELECT ID, AVG(Score) FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Any idea?

Comment: in what language anyway? :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
from t in myTable
group t by new {
  t.ID
} into g
select new {
  Average = g.Average(p => p.Score),
  g.Key.ID
}
```

or *Lambda*

```
myTable.GroupBy(t => new  {ID = t.ID})
   .Select (g => new {
            Average = g.Average (p => p.Score), 
            ID = g.Key.ID 
         })
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in Linq-to-Objects would be something like the below.

```
var results = from row in myTable
              group row by row.Id into rows 
              select new 
              {
                  Id = rows.Key,
                  AverageScore = rows.Average(row => row.Score)
              };
```

It's only slightly different for an ORM like entity framework. Namely, you would need to go through the data context or an appropriate DbSet/ObjectSet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _result =   from a in myTable
                group a by a.ID into g
                select new
                {
                    ID = g.Key.ID,
                    AverageResult = g.Average(x => x.Score)
                }
```

Comment: Note that `g.Key.ID` will not exist and will not compile. Only `g.Key` is needed in this snippet.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram why it won't compile? I just tested it.

Comment: This version? You should get an error message roughly stating "'int' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting..." (Substituting `int` for whatever the actual property type is for ID.)  The point is that `g.Key` *is* the ID. It's not an object containing an ID property.