# From SQL to C# LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq

I have some problems with translation of SQL to LINQ, precisely with mix of Group by and Average. I have tried solve it in different ways, but without expected result.

SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
  AVG([Grade])
  ,[User].FirstName
  ,[User].Surname
  ,[Student].StudentID
  ,[Student].ClassID

FROM [Szkola].[dbo].[School_Class]
JOIN [Szkola].[dbo].[Student]
ON School_Class.ClassID = Student.ClassID
JOIN [Szkola].[dbo].[School_Grades] 
ON Student.StudentID = School_Grades.StudentID
JOIN [Szkola].[dbo].[Teacher] 
ON Teacher.TeacherID = School_Grades.TeacherID
JOIN [Szkola].[dbo].[User]
ON Student.UserID = [User].UserID

WHERE [Teacher].[Subject] = 'Mathematics'
GROUP BY [Student].[StudentID], [Student].[ClassID], [User].[FirstName], 
[User].[Surname]
ORDER BY AVG([Grade]) DESC
```

Could you also describe how exactly works your solution? I read about LINQ and Group by, but I think I will better understand it on this example.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to search for and read some of the tutorials. Have you tried anything using LINQ so far

Comment: do a google search on SQL Average and GroupBy Linq has nothing to do with the definition of the 2 but it's best you understand what it is in regards to Aggregates etc.. I would start there.. 1000's of sql function examples / explanation online

Comment: Can you please show the code of your effort, it might be a good starting point. We do help people with specific problems but we are not here to write it for you.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696817/translate-sql-to-lambda-linq-with-groupby-and-average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using classes to simulate your database

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<School_Class> classes = new List<School_Class>();
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            List<School_Grade> grades = new List<School_Grade>();
            List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
            List<User> users = new List<User>();

            var query = (from c in classes
                         join s in students on c.ClassID equals s.ClassID
                         join g in grades on s.StudentID equals g.StudentID
                         join t in teachers on s.StudentID equals t.TeacherID
                         join u in users on s.UserID equals u.UserID
                         select new { c = c, s = s, g = g, t = t, u = u })
                .Where(x => x.t.Subject == "Mathematics")
                .GroupBy(x => new { 
                     student = x.s.StudentID, 
                     _class = x.c.ClassID, 
                     firstname = x.u.FirstName, 
                     surname = x.u.SurName })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstOrDefault().g.grades.Average())
                .Select(x => new { firstname = x.Key.firstname, 
                                   surname = x.Key.surname, 
                                   sid = x.Key.student, 
                                   cid = x.Key._class, 
                                   avg = x.FirstOrDefault().g.grades.Average() })
                .Take(3).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class School_Class
    {
        public int ClassID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int ClassID { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
    }
    public class School_Grade
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public int TeacherID { get; set; }
        public List<int> grades { get; set; }
    }
    public class Teacher
    {
        public int TeacherID { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
    }
```